# How to resolve the error that is popping up in SharePoint while create a list by using the excel in the same SharePoint Online site

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, power-automate

I am trying to create a SharePoint list by using the excel table in the same SharePoint site. SharePoint is showing the table name, but it is showing the below error when am trying to create the list. Please help how to rectify the error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please close the dialog, refresh the page, create the list from excel file again to compare the result.

If the issue still exists, please create a new simple table in excel file, then create list based on it to check the result.